# Converting number to an actual time string in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to convert 83012 (an int) to '8:30:12' (a string) in matlab. I couldn't find any clear answer. The real problem is adding the colons. Any help is appreciated.

```
%Get the start time value from User
str1     = get(handles.StartEditTag, 'string');
newstr1  = erase(str1, ':'); %Take out colons (eg '6:30:00' -> '63000')
startVal = str2num(newstr1); %Convert string to num (eg '63000' -> 63000)

%Get the end time value from the User
str2    = get(handles.EndEditTag, 'string');
newstr2 = erase(str2, ':'); 
endVal  = str2num(newstr2); 

roundStart = mod(startVal, 100); %(eg 63000 -> 00)
roundEnd   = mod(endVal, 100);

if mod(roundStart, 15) ~= 0
    %Round to the nearest multiple of 15 (eg 83027 -> 83030)
    startVal = Roundto15(roundStart, startVal); %function I made to round
end

if mod(roundEnd, 15) ~= 0
    endVal   = Roundto15(roundEnd, endVal);
end

startString = int2str(startVal); %(eg 83030 -> '83030')
endString   = int2str(endVal);
```

I'm taking a time interval from the user and making sure it's in 15 second intervals. This is what I have so far.

Comment: That seems easy. Show your code and someone will quickly tell you how to add the colons

Comment: Just posted what I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your integer always has 5 or 6 digits

```
time_int=83012;
time_str=num2str(time_int);
result=strcat(time_str(1:end-4),':',time_str(end-3:end-2),':',time_str(end-1:end));
```

**Edit:** A nicer way to do the whole thing

```
% The string you get from the user
str1 = '16:30:12';

% Extraing hours, minutes, seconds
C1 = textscan(str1,'%d:%d:%d');

% converting the time to seconds
time1_in_seconds = double((C1{1}*3600)+(C1{2}*60)+C1{3});

% rounding to 15 sec
time1_in_seconds_round15 = round(time1_in_seconds/15)*15;

% getting the new hours, minutes and seconds
hours = floor(time1_in_seconds_round15/3600);
minutes = floor((time1_in_seconds_round15 - hours*3600)/60);
seconds = time1_in_seconds_round15 - hours*3600 - minutes*60;

% getting the string
s = sprintf('%d:%d:%d', hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

First do your arithmetic to compute the hours, minutes and seconds, then use string formatting:

```
s = sprintf('%d:%02d:%02d', hours, minutes, seconds)
```